# Mocking Generic Repository unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm creating a unit test and i'm using rhino mocks (i've never worked with any kind of mocks before, (if you guys know how to handle it with another mock framework, please show me some examples with them)).

In my scenario i'm trying to mock the following generic repository

```
public interface Repository
{
  IEnumerable<TEntity> Search(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> order = null);
}
```

My unit test:

```
 _classRepository.Stub(x => x.Search(myclass =>
                             myclass.id == 1 &&
                            ).Return(arrayClass.AsQueryable());
```

the array class has only one register with id 1.

When i run my test i receive the following message:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source

Comment: My mistake about the question title: (Unit )

Comment: Then just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40792410/edit) the question title. Also the question is incomplete. provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MarioGuadanhim the stub you've added has a typo, it won't compile... please a you complete UT.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the tips

Comment: @OldFox actually it does, the only problem is "the error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" when i use it. Could you explain more about it? I'm newbie with unit test and I did not find anything on stackoverflow so far.

Comment: @MarioGuadanhim `myclass =>
                             myclass.id == 1 &&
                            ` is a syntax error. In my comment I had some typos, it had to be: "please add a complete UT". If you won't add your UT code then I won't be able to help you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem when changed my mock framework to Moq.
So i could use the lambda expressions on my mock setup.

```
_myclassRepository.Setup(x => x.Search(
          myclass => myclass.id == 1,
          It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<MyClass>, IOrderedQueryable<MyClass>>>(),
          It.IsAny<string>(),
          It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(arrMyClass);
```

Comment: Before updating to Moq, did you fix the syntax error in your original code? `_classRepository.Stub(x => x.Search(myclass =>
                             myclass.id == 1 &&
                            ).Return(arrayClass.AsQueryable());`

Comment: yes i did, actually, there is no sintax error, I just improved my code to post here then i forgot to remove the "&&"